# Arranging data for Heatmap Visualization with Seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

I am trying to create a heatmap, with the y Axis with the Criteria Column, as seen below, and the x, with all the other columns (Robustness, Stability, etc.) However, most of the tutorials I come across just use 1 column, i.e., the common flights example with prices and years. I basically just want there to be 1 color if it is a 1, and another color if it is a 0.

Any assistance would be great, thanks!

df head snippet

```
Criteria,Robustness,Stability,Flexibility,Resourcefulness,Coordination Capacitiy,Redundancy,Diversity,Foresight Capacity,Independence,Connectivity & Interdependence,Collaboration Capacity,Agility,Adaptability,Self-Organization,Creativity & Innovation,Efficiency,Equity
Ecosystem Monitoring & Protection,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0
Using local and native material and species ,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1
Erosion protection,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1
Protection of wetlands and watersheds,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1
Availability and accessibility of resources,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1
Reduction of environmental impacts,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1
Quality of resources,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0
Biodiversity and wildlife conservation,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1
"Material and resource management (production, consumption, conservation, recycling etc)",1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1
```

Comment: What is the problem? If i make a variable: x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 100)).round(0).astype('int') and plot it as sns.heatmap(x) i get a normal heatmap. Are your variables integers?

Comment: I have set the index to Criteria, however, how do I ensure that criteria column/index is the vertical y axis in the heatmap, as now I get the error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Ecosystem Monitoring & Protection'' as it is trying to use the criteria map as part of the heatmap.

Comment: Can you put in the matrix you're with?

Comment: Your post is missing the code you tried.  You can create your heatmap with either `sns.heatmap(df.set_index('Criteria'), ...)` or the transposed `sns.heatmap(df.set_index('Criteria').T, ...)` if you want the criteria for the columns. Could you add some code to create a minimal reproducible example, to make your question clearer and easier to answer?  You could further try `sns.clustermap(df.set_index('Criteria'), ...)` to maybe get some additional insights via clustering similar criteria or features.

Comment: Note that the strings for criteria and the column names are very long.  These won't fit nicely on a plot.  You might want to replace them using abbreviations and introducing newlines (`'\n'`) to write them on two or more lines.

Comment: Thank you @JohanC this {sns.heatmap(df.set_index('Criteria').T,)}    solved my issue. I also changed the column names to be shorter, now will just style it. Thank you!